# Perl Windows CPANM proxy issue

Tags: windows, perl, proxy, cpan, cpanm

After solving a few issues, I've Succeeded with CPAN on my Work Windows 7 Machine with DwimPerl via `perl -MCPAN -e shell` and `o conf init /proxy/`

```
ftp:
http: http://192.168.1.1:8080
no:
Username: Chris@work
Password: SuperDeDuperSecretPassword
```

CPAN works. I'm able to install/build.

It seems that no matter what I do, CPANM doesn't want to get past the proxy:

```
C:\>cpanm WWW::Mechanize
! Finding WWW::Mechanize on cpanmetadb failed.
501 protocol scheme 'wwwproxy.work.com' is not supported
C:\> cpan WWW::Mechanize
...
...
...
c:\Programs\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.exe INSTALL -- OK
```

What's different between the two and what would cause CPAN to succeed while CPANM fails with a 501?

Comment: Just figured it out with a minor reminder from a coworker. I was focused on `cpan -MCPAN -e shell` -> `o conf init /proxy/` ... but the issue was actually with Windows System variables. Added an answer.

Comment: @serenesat That question is "CPAN is failing" - nothing in the question mentions CPANM and it's on Linux. This question is `CPAN is running successfuly, CPANM is failing` - CPANM and on Windows.  Closely related, but very much not a dupe. That question was solved with LWP. This one was solved with `o conf init /proxy/` AND Windows User Variables.

Comment: Then heading should be change from _CPAN/CPANM proxy issue_ to _CPANM proxy issue_.

Comment: And its closely related thats why its written _possible duplicate_ not _duplicate_.

Comment: Updated title, and was just explaining the differences - atleast how I see/meant them.

Answer (score 4):

10 minutes after I posted this, I had a brief conversation with a coworker. He mentioned environment variables. I verified that I had indeed added Windows Environment variables previously. A quick update to them:

```
User Variables for Chris:
HTTP_Proxy:  http://192.168.1.1:8080
HTTP_proxy_pass: SuperDeDuperSecretPassword
HTTP_proxy_user: Chris@Work
```

I changed it from `wwwproxy.work.org` to `http://192.168.1.1:80` (CPAN complained without the HTTP, so I think it needed the full URL as well).

AND I had a typo in my name :(

CPANM works now.