Unable to install modules from CPAN, "could not find release" error
I have been trying for several days and simply cannot figure out why this keeps failing. I am using a proxy to get out of our internal network. It says that it cannot find App::cpanminus which is strange because it is definitely there. Can anyone suggest something that I could try to move forward with this problem?
# export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
[root@vm]# cpanm -v App::cpanminus
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7047 on perl 5.026003 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Work directory is /root/.cpanm/work/1728941689.1094777
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.72
You have /usr/bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.30
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching App::cpanminus () on cpanmetadb ...
! Finding App::cpanminus on cpanmetadb failed.
! Could not find a release matching App::cpanminus on MetaCPAN.
Searching App::cpanminus on mirror http://www.cpan.org ...
Downloading index file http://www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz ...
! Finding App::cpanminus () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution App::cpanminus
Expiring 1 work directories.

cpan[3]> o conf /proxy/
$CPAN::Config options from /root/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm:

ftp_proxy          [http://proxy-uat.mycompnay.com:8080]
http_proxy         [http://proxy-uat.mycompnay.com:8080]
no_proxy           []
proxy_pass         undef
proxy_user         []



# wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080 https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7047.tar.gz
--2024-10-14 21:39:50--  https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7047.tar.gz
Resolving proxy-uat.mycompany.com (proxy-uat.mycompany.com)... 10.202.192.1, 10.202.192.32
Connecting to proxy-uat.mycompany.com (proxy-uat.mycompany.com)|10.202.192.1|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 316779 (309K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘App-cpanminus-1.7047.tar.gz

App-cpanminus-1.704 100%[===================>] 309.35K  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s   

2024-10-14 21:39:50 (11.6 MB/s) - ‘App-cpanminus-1.7047.tar.gz’ saved [316779/316779]

[root@vm]# ls -l App-cpanminus-1.7047.tar.gz 
-rw------- 1 root root 316779 Jul 30  2023 App-cpanminus-1.7047.tar.gz

# cat ~/.wgetrc 
use_proxy=yes
http_proxy=http://proxy-uat.mycompany.com:8080
https_proxy=http://proxy-uat.mycompany.com:8080
ftp_proxy=http://proxy-uat.mycompany.com:8080


I didn't had the same exact issue as you're referring to above although my search reached your post, here were my bumps:
13.93 ! Finding App::cpanminus on cpanmetadb failed.
14.04 ! Finding App::cpanminus () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
14.04 ! Couldn't find module or a distribution App::cpanminus

I fixed it by adding the following variables (building a Docker image here):
ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"
ENV http_proxy="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"
ENV https_proxy="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"
ENV ALL_PROXY="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"
ENV all_proxy="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"

Only using these (ALL IN CAPITALS) failed with the above mentioned errors:
ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"
ENV ALL_PROXY="http://prx.domain.suffix:8080/"

Hope this helps.

OP has already set proxies correctly as shown in their question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563834/how-can-cpanm-retrieve-settings-for-a-proxy-that-requires-username-and-password
